# Addressing ranges in a Scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large matrix, currently in numpy that i would like to port over to scipy sparse matrix, because saving the text representations of the numpy (2000,2000) matrix is over 100mb.

(1) There seem to a surfeit of sparse matrices available in scipy [for instance, [lil_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html) or [dok_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html)- which one would be optimal for simple incrementing, and efficient to save to a database?

(2) 
I'd like to be able to address ranges in the matrix like so:

```
>> import numpy as np    
>> a = np.zeros((1000,1000))
>> a[3:5,4:7] += 1
```

It seems that this is not possible for the sparse matrices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't say which is most efficient to store.  It's going to depend on your data.

I can say, however that the `+=` operator works, just that you can't rely on the usual array broadcasting rules:

```
>>> m = sparse.lil_matrix((100,100))
>>> m[50:56,50:56]+=scipy.ones((6,6))
>>> m[50,50]  #1.0
```

Comment: The `+=` operator only works for `lil` matrices - try `m = sparse.csr_matrix((100,100)); m[50:56,50:56]+=scipy.ones((6,6))` and you'll get a `NotImplementedError` (scipy 0.14.0.dev-86f95bd)